# how can I detect if a recurring word is in an array java

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program where one can input words, which are added to an array, until the same word is entered twice. Then the program breaks.

Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in); 

    while (true) {
    System.out.println("Type a word: ");
    String word = reader.nextLine();
    words.add(word); 
    if (words.contains(word)) {
        System.out.println("You typed the word: " + word + " twice.");
        break;
    }
```

Every time I enter a single word, the program says "You have typed the word twice." I need to find a way to distinguish the items in the array from one another. Is it possible to use a for block? 
Thank you.

Comment: Check if the word exists in the array _before_ adding it yourself.

Comment: first you add the word, and then you check if it is there. it will always be there of course

Comment: if all you are doing is checking for duplicate words a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) would be better than an ArrayList. If you need to track order use a `LinkedHashSet`, otherwise a plain `HashSet` would do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding `word` to `words` before doing the `contains` check.

```
if (words.contains(word)) {
    System.out.println("You typed the word: " + word + " twice.");
    break;
} else {
    words.add(word);
}
```

will resolve this.

You should also consider making `words` a `Set`, which has faster lookups and doesn't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly improved version would be to use a `Set`: its `add` method returns `false` when the element is already present (and it's more efficient than a list to "find" an element - although in your case, because there is only a small number of words, it won't make any noticeable difference).

```
Set<String> words = new HashSet<> ();

while (true) {
  System.out.println("Type a word: ");
  String word = reader.nextLine();
  if (!words.add(word)) {
    System.out.println("You typed the word: " + word + " twice.");
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: You beat me ... I would personnaly use a `do{ String word = reader.nextLine(); }while(words.add(word));` to remove the break.

Comment: @AxelH but then `word` is out of scope for the last println ;-)

Comment: Outside of comment section I would declare `word` before the loop ;) in scope and always initialized. But to messy on a one line code... (don't want to write an answer just for minor preferences...)